# How to Add String with Range A1

Tags: excel, vba

I have String in `Sheet1.Range(B2)` that is `Anything` I want to paste it into `Sheet2.Range(B2)` as `Dear Anything,`

Any help will be highly appreciated.

I could not find and add string in below code any help will be highly appreciated.

```
Sheet2.Range("A2") = Sheet1.Range("B2")
```

Comment: `Sheet2.Range("B2") = "Dear " & Sheet1.Range("B2")`

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook:  ... `& ","`? Probably.

Comment: @VBasic2008 ah yes... missed that comma.  `Sheet2.Range("B2") = "Dear " & Sheet1.Range("B2") & ", "`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Adding" strings is generally called "concatenation".

There are two ways to concatenate strings in Excel:

As mentioned, you can use the `&` operator (can also be used outside of VBA):

```
Sheet1.Range("B2").Value = Sheet1.Range(A2").Value & " " & Sheet1.Range("B2")
```

There is also the `TextJoin()` function. In basic Excel (outside of VBA), it looks as follows:

```
=TextJoin(";";FALSE;A1:A3)
```

The latter stands for:

- Join the cells from A1 to A3.
- Use a ";" between the cell values.
- Don't skip empty cells.

You can use this in VBA as `Application.WorksheetFunction.TextJoin()`.